# SASS Invalid css error

Tags: ruby, sass

I just started with sass and installed prepros. I tried to compile an .scss file and got an error:

`Syntax error: Invalid CSS after "  color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@blue;"`

The .scss code:

```
.footer {
clear: both;
background-color: @blue;
```

}

I installed Ruby, and prepros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SCSS uses `$` to denote variables so it should be `background-color: $blue;`

Comment: Owwww man, that is some stupid mistake... Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your syntax is wrong. In Sass, `@` is for things like [imports](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import), [media directives](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#media), [partials](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) (includes) and [extends](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#extends).

If you want to define a specific value for blue, and then reuse it, then the syntax is something like this:

```
$blue: #3333FF;

a {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: $blue;
}
```