# Invalid CSS when using twitter-bootstrap with scss in a Rails 4 app

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

I am using [twitter-bootstra-rails](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) gem in my Rails app.

Here is how my manifest (application.css) looks:

```
 *= require_self
 @import bootstrap_and_overrides;
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

However, when trying to use a variable like this:

```
color: @brand-success;
```

I get:

```
Invalid CSS after "      color: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "@brand-success; "
```

What am I missing? In the docs it says:

> If you are using SASS to compile your application.css (e.g. your
>   manifest file is application.css.sass or application.css.scss) you may
>   get this:
>
> Invalid CSS after "*": expected "{", was "= require twitt..." (in
>   app/assets/stylesheets/application.css) (sass)
>
> If this is the case, you must use @import instead of *= in your
>   manifest file, or don't compile your manifest with SASS.

Comment: try create a new file called name `whatever.css.scss` and put this `@import "bootstrap_and_overrides";` or if not working change `color: @brand-success;` to `color: $brand-success;` references : [ref 1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17180681/1297435) & [ref 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19792684/1297435)

Comment: Looks like  you have to use `$brand-success`  instead of `@brand-success`

Comment: Are you using LESS or Sass?  You can't really use both together.

Comment: I am using Sass, but as the docs of the gem says, if you want to use the less variables, you have to use @import. That is what I have done, but it is not working.

Comment: BTW, Why the downvote guys?